# ListBox C# get selected item Metro App

Tags: c#, listbox, microsoft-metro

I'm making a app for windows using listboxes. But I have one problem, I don't know how to set a selected item from listbox in a variable. I've tried to use `listbox.selectedItem.toString()` but doesnt work.

Comment: Show your full work..

Comment: are you trying to get multiple selected Items?

Comment: No, how can i take one item with multiple selected items?

Comment: @HugoNeto which one do you want among multi selected items? the first? the last? or anything else based on your rule?

Comment: I just want to take the item who user selected. its like "my rule"

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure, what you are asking for.

If you want to select multiple lines you can use following code:

```
        listBox1.Items.Add("A");
        listBox1.Items.Add("B");
        listBox1.Items.Add("C");
        listBox1.Items.Add("D");
        listBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended;

        listBox1.SetSelected(1, true);
        listBox1.SetSelected(3, true);
```

If you want to iterate over all selected Items, you can use:

```
        foreach (var item in listBox1.SelectedItems)
        {                
            //will return "B" and "D"
            string item0 = item.ToString();
        }
```

Or if you want to get the first or last selected Item you can use:

```
        //Will return "B"
        string item1 = listBox1.SelectedItems[0].ToString();
        //Will return "D"
        string item2 = listBox1.SelectedItems[listBox1.SelectedItems.Count - 1].ToString();
```

If you use the above code to get the last or the first item, you have to check first if an item is selected - otherwise you will get an exception if no item is selected